# vCard photo being stripped

Tags: outlook, jpeg, outlook-2010, vcf-vcard

I am building a "Meet The Team" page and thought it would be a nice feature to have downloadable vCards for each member. I save the vCard in .vcf format with the persons photo (.jpg) but for some reason the photo is not being saved. When I view the vCard I see the placeholder image. I made the vCards inside Outlook 2010, should I be using a different program?

Comment: A sample vCard would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check to make sure that there is a photo attached to the vCard.  Open the vCard in a text editor and look for a "PHOTO" property, like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:John Doe
PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG:492957a0b847c934d
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Thank you, figured it out. The photos I was trying to save were in the wrong format.